# Unsupported operand type for %: 'Int64Index' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm facing some trouble trying to do this:

```
ratings_table = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv', sep=',') 
k = 10
for i in xrange(k):
    training = ratings_table.ix[ratings_table.index % k != i]
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: For me it works, what is your pandas version? `print (pd.show_versions())`

Comment: The version of pandas that I'm using is 0.15.0.

Comment: last version is `0.19.2`, there it works perfectly.

Comment: Also `ix` is not necessary - `training = ratings_table[ratings_table.index % k != i]` - [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)